# How to pass a byte array to union that has multiple structs in CGO

Tags: c++, c, go, union, cgo

I'm using a byte array (from golang) to pass values to a union (in c++) which has multiple structs but I couldn't find out how to do it correctly. The value I set is getting assigned to all the structs in that union even though my intention is to set it to one of them.

In the below example, map_id, start_id and prog_id gets the same value (5) in the cpp program even though my intention is to pass the value to just the start_id. Could you please suggest how to achieve this?

// example.h

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

typedef union bpf_attr
{
    // BPF_MAP_GET_FD_BY_ID
    unsigned map_id; ///< ID of map for BPF_MAP_GET_FD_BY_ID to find.

    struct
    {
        unsigned start_id; ///< ID to look for an ID after. The start_id need not exist.
        unsigned next_id;  ///< On return, contains the next ID.
    }bpf_next_id;          ///< Attributes used by BPF_PROG_GET_NEXT_ID, BPF_MAP_GET_NEXT_ID, and BPF_LINK_GET_NEXT_ID.

    // BPF_PROG_TEST_RUN
    struct
    {
        unsigned prog_fd;       ///< File descriptor of program to run.
        unsigned retval;        ///< On return, contains the return value of the program.
        unsigned data_size_in;  ///< Size in bytes of input data.
        unsigned data_size_out; ///< Size in bytes of output data.
        unsigned long long  data_in;      ///< Pointer to input data.
        unsigned long long data_out;      ///< Pointer to output data.
        unsigned duration;      ///< Duration in milliseconds to run the program.
        unsigned ctx_size_in;   ///< Size in bytes of input context.
        unsigned ctx_size_out;  ///< Size in bytes of output context.
        unsigned long long ctx_in;        ///< Pointer to input context.
        unsigned long long ctx_out;       ///< Pointer to output context.
        unsigned flags;         ///< Flags (currently 0).
        unsigned cpu;           ///< CPU to run the program on.
        unsigned batch_size;    ///< Number of times to run the program in a batch.
        unsigned repeat;        ///< Number of times to repeat the program.
    } test;                     ///< Attributes used by BPF_PROG_TEST_RUN.
}bpf_attr1;

int display(union bpf_attr* attr, unsigned int size);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

// example.cpp

```
#include "example.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int display(union bpf_attr* attr, unsigned int size) {
    printf("Map id %d \n", attr->map_id);
    printf("start_id %d \n", attr->bpf_next_id.start_id);
    printf("prog_fd %d \n", attr->test.prog_fd);
    attr->bpf_next_id.next_id = 25;
    return 0;
}
```

// main.go

```
package main

/*
#cgo CFLAGS: -I /cwrapper
#cgo LDFLAGS: -L. -lexample -L /cwrapper/out
#include "example.h"
*/
import "C"
import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
bpfAttr := new(C.union_bpf_attr)
bpfAttr[0] = 5
bpfAttrSize := C.uint(unsafe.Sizeof(bpfAttr))
C.display(bpfAttr, bpfAttrSize)
}
```

Comment: Because `union` members overlap in memory there is no way you will get good guarantees about reading from `attr->map_id` and `attr->bpf_next_id.start_id` one after the other.

Comment: Note that C is much more forgiving than C++ with respect to `union`s, so you may want to remove the C tag or the C++ tag (question reads like you should remove the C tag) depending on which of the two you're actually targeting to get the best possible answer.

Comment: In modern C++, consider using [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch unfortunately I don't have control on the C++ code, I'm trying to consume that from a go package